# Bind Listview Items to Infobox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

How can I bind the listview Item Properties of a selected item?
[image: Infobox at the right]

At the left side I show my files with sites in the listview and at the right i want to show the name, number of sites etc in a kind of Infobox (Grid with labels).
So how can I bind the list[index].name to the name label when i select it in the listview?

Or should I work with Selection Changed Event?

Comment: can you show us your code, what have you tried? it's WPF or Winforms?

Comment: it´s wpf..  I have written a simple File class with save path and name and so on. that i have binded via `observableCollection` and in xaml via `<ListView.View>
                <GridView><GridViewColumn
                        Width="160"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                        Header="Name" />`

Answer (score 0):

You Could bind the `SelectedItem` property of the GridView to your property on the ViewModel:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,  Mode=TwoWay}"  >
 .....
</DataGrid>
```

and in SelectedItem property:

```
private YourItemType_selectedItem;
public YourItemType SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if(value != _selectedItem)
        {
           _selectedItem = value;

           NotifyOfPropertyChange("SelectedItem");

           // notify InfoBox property changed
           NotifyOfPropertyChange("InfoBoxItem");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the TextBlocks/TextBoxes in the InfoBox to the SelectedItem property of the ListView.

Give the ListView an x:Name:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pos}" Header="Pos." />
            <GridViewColumn Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Seitenzahl}" Header="Seitenzahl" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

...and use use an ElementName binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=listView}" /> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Pos, ElementName=listView}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Seitenzahl, ElementName=listView}" />
```

"Name", "Pos" and "Seitenzahl" are the name of the same properties that you bind to and display in the columns of the ListView.